# How do I add multiple joins (Fetches) to a joined table using nhibernate and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have these tables /entities

**VacationRequestDate** table which has a ***VacationRequestId*** field that links with **VacationRequest**  table
**VacationRequest** has ***PersonId*** and ***RequestStatusId*** fields that links with **Person** and **RequestStatus** respectively.

i have this query so far:

```
IEnumerable<VacationRequestDate> dates = Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>().Fetch(r => r.VacationRequest).ThenFetch(p=>p.RequestStatus).ToList();
```

this works fine and joins with **VacationRequest** and then **VacationRequest** joins with **RequestStatus** but i can't figure out how to add an additional EAGER join to the **VacationRequest** table.

If i add a **Fetch** at the end, it refers to the **VacationRequestDate** table
If i add a **ThenFetch** at the end, it refers to the **RequestStatus** table

I can't find any api that will refer to the VacationRequest table as the reference point.

how would you add multiple joins to a joined table using nhibernate LINQ ?

Comment: @Jani - i am using the LINQ API (not the Criteria API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not 100% optimal because of an additional join, this works:

```
Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>()
       .Fetch(r => r.VacationRequest).ThenFetch(p => p.RequestStatus)
       .Fetch(r => r.VacationRequest).ThenFetch(p => p.Person)
```

The other querying methods (HQL, Criteria, not sure about QueryOver) don't have this limitation.